# Selecting guess matrix for Newton method to calculate inverse of a matrix

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I have implemented the newton method  as follows to calculate inverse of a matrix(input in my case)and x0 being the initial guess matrix.But the value of the iteration is not stable.I suspect the problem is in assigning the right x0 matrix.?

```
while(error>1e-3)
{   
    xk=x0*2-x0*input*x0;
}
```

Comment: You need that the initial residual is rather small. `||I-x0*input||<1`. If a useful initial approximation exists that is not also already the final approximation depends on the matrix class that you have as input.

Comment: @LutzLehmann is there any generalized way so that I can generate x0 matrix depending on the given input matrix programatically

Comment: As I said, without computing the mostly exact inverse via QR or LU decomposition this is in general not possible. There are special classes where pre-processing routines exist that deliver approximate inverses, such as for diagonally dominant matrices or the ILU decomposition for sparse matrices, but as said, they are special.